# "Content Encoding Error" when I try to gzip the output

Tags: grails, gzip

I'm trying to gzip the output of my controller action to save some bandwidth:

```
new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream{ baos ->
  new GZIPOutputStream( baos ).withWriter{ it << m.text.bytes }
  //def gzip = baos.toByteArray().encodeBase64()
  def gzip = new String( baos.toByteArray() )
  response.setHeader 'Content-Type', 'application/x-javascript'
  response.setHeader 'Content-Encoding', 'x-gzip'
  response.outputStream.withStream{ it << gzip }
}
```

}

when I open the url in a browser it gives me

> Unknown Error: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

in IE
or

> Content Encoding Error

in FF

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you check if you are not saving you file with an utf-8 BOM? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom) You need a good editor to notice the difference.

Comment: Also if php error_reporting is on, this can give problems.

Comment: no, there's no BOM problem and it has nothing to do with php

Answer (score 1):

```
    def index() {
            response.setHeader 'Content-Type', 'application/x-javascript'
            response.setHeader 'Content-Encoding', 'x-gzip'
            new GZIPOutputStream(response.outputStream).withWriter{ it << "Content comes here" }
    }
```

also consider using the capabilities of a webserver in front of your webapp (e.g. apache's gzip module can handle things like this way better).  you would also have to check for the capabilities of the client first (`Accept-Encoding` header in the client request)